# jsdom: mixed-case parsing

Tags: jquery, node.js, screen-scraping, jsdom

I'm using jQuery with jsdom (0.2.10). For some reason node.exe (0.6.5.1) never returns when dealing with HTML such as this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head></HEAD>
  <body></BODY>
</HTML>
```

The parsing code is:

```
var request = require('request'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom');

request({ uri:'http://localhost/test.html' }, function (error, response, body) {
  jsdom.env({
    html: body,
    scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'],
    done: function (err, window) {
      var $ = window.jQuery;  
      console.log('node.exe should get terminated after this line but does not.');    
    }
  });
});
```

Using same case for the tag names works as expected (i.e. node.exe returns). But since I have no control over HTML I'm parsing, I wonder if there is a way around this problem. Also, `body.toLowerCase()` helps in terminating node.exe, however it's not a viable solution because I need to preserve original case of the text nodes.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you given an example of the jsdom code you are running?

Comment: This is probably fixed in recent versions of jsdom; we've done substantial HTML parsing upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in `node-htmlparser` module. Parsing

```
<html><head></head><body>foo</body></html>
<html><head></HEAD><body>foo</BODY></HTML>
```

yields different results for each of the line.

[Here](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser/pull/41)'s my pull request for those interested.